# nodejs server started with forever is down

Tags: node.js, forever

I found multiple times my nodejs server down. I start it using forever.
The command `forever stopall` print this

```
 forever stopall
info:    Forever stopped processes:
data:        uid  command             script  forever pid   id logfile                          uptime
data:    [0] xYCo /usr/local/bin/node bin/www 26175   26184    /home/myuser/.forever/xYCo.log 7:17:34:38.102
```

but the server do not respond.
The command I use to start the server with forever is:

```
forever start --minUpTime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000  -a -o out.log -e err.log bin/www
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you examined `err.log` to see what's going?

Comment: yep I can't see any worrying error..just some invalid object access I already fixed.Anyway I already check if I throw an exception in an express route forever keep running.. that's why I'm confused